# XML feed does not validate, but syntax seems to be correct?

Tags: xml, feed

My XML feed for Trulia [found here](http://ilovetheupperwestside.com/trulia-feed/) doesn't seem to render correctly. But upon inspection all tags appear to be correctly nested and I don't see any errors with syntax.

W3C's feed validator outputs [this report](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Filovetheupperwestside.com%2Ftrulia-feed%2F), saying that the feed isn't well-formed, but it seems correctly formed to me?

```
column 39: Undefined root element: properties 
column 35473: XML parsing error: <unknown>:1:35497: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping illegal characters by wrapping them with CDDATA in the format `<![CDATA[foo]]>` cleared one of the issues, however this wasn't the only reason my feed wasn't being read.

The problem was that the MIME type for the feed was text/html instead of xml. I checked the MIME types configured on my server and saw no issues however.

I later discovered that it was a caching issue caused by a Wordpress plugin that operates in the same directory. By excluding that file in W3 Total Cache's whitelist the feed rendered correctly.

Comment: If you revert the escaping fix (no longer using CDATA sections), but do use the correct MIME type, would your feed be read? If not, "wasn't the _only_ reason" might be somewhat better wording.

Comment: (I honestly don't know if Trulia uses a conformant XML parser for their feeds -- in which case the entity escaping is mandatory -- or something more permissive; that said, an intentionally permissive backend probably would have ignored the Content-Type too).

Comment: Yes, I don't think the feed is very forgiving, but what's odd is that it seemed to be able to process illegal characters, although it completely gave up with the incorrect content type.

Answer (score 1):

Your (first) problem is here:

```
BROWNSTONE CONDO!Sunny & South facing
```

The `&` needs to be `&amp;`.

If you were using a proper XML generation library, it would be doing this for you. What are you doing presently?

Comment: Just outputting the XML manually by fetching the data from the database associated with my application and echoing it out, line by line.

Comment: You can't do that and expect it to work -- `echo` doesn't know how to do element escaping, and if you aren't doing element escaping, what you're writing isn't XML.

Comment: If you want something easy, try writing PYX -- it's a really trivial format to generate from scripts -- and using the `xmlstarlet p2x` command to modify that to real XML.

Comment: See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-matters17/ for an introduction to pyx.

Comment: Could I do it manually if I have a function that escapes all amperstands, triangle brackets and apostrophes before outputting the tag content?

Comment: That would cover the easy cases, but it still wouldn't get the oddballs -- and if your input includes unicode, there's a *lot* of oddballs. (You don't need to deal with apostrophes, by the way; they're safe to represent literally).

Comment: ...another 90% approach would to be to put all your content in CDATA sections, and avoid the need to escape content that way (unless, of course, that content includes the appropriate string to _end_ a CDATA section).

Comment: ...but why are you bothering with 90% approaches that'll eventually break when processing oddball input when you can use a library written by someone who put month/years into building something 100% compliant with the specification?

Comment: Just that I already created it and I'm not familiar with this library (yet), and I needed at least a quick fix for the time being.